# Cannot invoke transient magit-pull while minibuffer is active

Tags: magit, minibuffer

I'm using magit. When I try to pull or commit, I get this message in the mini-buffer:

```
Cannot invoke transient magit-pull while minibuffer is active
```

I can assure you, I have closed every magit-related buffer.  There is no magit process at all, no hidden buffers.

When I `C-x g` to start magit back up, I see this error.  How can I identify and stop whatever process is blocking me from using magit?

I can use git pull, git commit etc., fine in other shells outside of emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking more general, more often than necessary I find myself in the minibuffer and pressing `Ctrl-g` does not end the minibuffer input session.
By running `Alt-X apropos-command` (aka `Ctrl-h a`) with 'minibuffer' as search term, I know found the command `exit-minibuffer`, which resolves the situation of not being able to apply a magit command.

Comment: `exit-minibuffer` worked for me. thanks!